# Can I use <f:setPropertyActionListener> inside an autoComplete component? 

Tags: jsf

Can I use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` inside an autoComplete component?

The autoComplete uses the managedbean `mbAC` for example and I want to send the `cliCod` from it to another bean with:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{targetBean.cliCod}" value="#{mbAC}" />
```

Is `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` the right way to do this?

Comment: Why can you not just set an actionListener on the component and assign the value to the target managed property from code?

Comment: It is a component that I only include in my code with ui:include so I cant really change its code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` works only inside a component implementing [`ActionSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/ActionSource.html) interface, such as `<h:commandButton>`, `<h:commandLink>`. It's unclear what autocomplete component you're talking about, but the PrimeFaces `<p:autoComplete>` doesn't implement it.

You need to look for an alternate solution, such as placing the bean in the right scope and/or using `@ManagedProperty` and/or using `<p:ajax>` instead. The exact solution depends on the concrete functional requirement which you didn't tell anything about.

In the future questions it would be more helpful for us and yourself if you ask how to achieve the given functional requirement instead of asking how to achieve a solution of which you thought that it's the right solution but which after all isn't.

Comment: I'll find a solution to my problem, but you gave me exactly what I was looking for with this question, wich is: where can I use (and how) f:setPropertyActionListener. Thanks. EDIT: and yes, it was a p:autocomplete